# PC just reboots after installing XanMod kernel

Tags: upgrade, kernel

The XanMod kernel description seemed good so Ι wanted to test it out. Ι did what it said on [XanMod's kernel page](https://xanmod.org/):

> 1. Register the PGP key:
>
>    ```
>    wget -qO - https://dl.xanmod.org/archive.key | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/xanmod-archive-keyring.gpg
>    ```
> 2. Add the repository:
>
>    ```
>    echo 'deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/xanmod-archive-keyring.gpg] http://deb.xanmod.org releases main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xanmod-release.list
>    ```
> 3. Then update and install:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt update && sudo apt install linux-xanmod-x64v3
>    ```
> 4. Reboot.

After that I tried booting the XanMod kernel several times with different options and it just rebooted my PC every single time. However, it did not even try to boot up the kernel.

I'm using a Lenovo IdeaPad 3 14IGL05 laptop.

From `/proc/cpuinfo`:

```
vendor_id    : GenuineIntel 
cpu family   : 6 
model        : 122 
model name   : Intel(R) Pentium(R) Silver N5030 CPU @ 1.10GHz
```

Comment: Just a side note: I looked into the description for that kernel and honestly couldn’t find a reason why it might be needed on a Desktop installation (*just to keep a limited perspective*) … Needless to say that installing it might cause issues down the road and will render your system unsupported AFAIK

Comment: @Raffa I think installing that kernel will still keep the normal Ubuntu kernels, so you can always boot into a default kernel afaik... There may be any number of reasons for running/trying a custom kernel.

Comment: Also, it says the usecases are: "eSport clients, streaming, live production".. That would sound like desktop systems to me .. 

Comment: @ArturMeinild Customized/special kernels have their uses/needs no argument here and even some are in the official Ubuntu repositories with updates and support included and, moreover, some like HWE are even selected by default during installation on some hardware … But, this one, while might has its use, has this stated: "… and some other dkms modules may not officially support EDGE and RT branch kernels." … Hence my humble opinion in the above comment … Still merely an opinion though :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's dig further into your hardware.

You have an Intel Pentium Silver N5030 CPU. Googling this gives the following [spec sheet](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/197308/intel-pentium-silver-n5030-processor-4m-cache-up-to-3-10-ghz/specifications.html).

Here, you can see the CPU family is "Products formerly Gemini Lake Refresh".

Moving on to [XanMod.org](https://xanmod.org/), we can see in the table that `x86-64-v2` is required for the "Intel Goldmont Plus (Gemini Lake)" architecture.

[image]

This means you tried to install v3 of the kernel, where you instead should have installed v2. And it did state *"Check platform compatibility in x86-64 psABI level reference below."*.

So remove variant 3:

```
sudo apt remove linux-xanmod-x64v3
```

And install variant 2 instead:

```
sudo apt install linux-xanmod-x64v2
```

See if that works. And yes, the instruction on their webpage can be misleading. Write to them if you would have them correct the page.